# Webpack loader not being used when requiring file being processed by custom loader

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-loader

I'm trying to write a custom Webpack loader that reads a JavaScript file and exports SASS variables, similar to [js-to-sass-var-loader](https://github.com/tompascall/js-to-sass-var-loader) but with some added functionality.

#### /webpack-loaders/js-to-sass-loader.js

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
import path from 'path';

const importRegex = /@import\s+'([^']+\.js)'\s*;/ig;

/* 
    functions for transforming...
*/

export default function (content) {
    let self = this;

    // search for "@import '*.js';" and replace that text with
    // the transformed output of the specified JavaScript file
    return content.replace(importRegex, (match, relativePath) => {
        if (match) {
            let modulePath = path.join(self.context, relativePath);
            self.addDependency(modulePath);
            let data = require(modulePath).default;
            return transform(data);
        }
    });
}
```

This JavaScript file loads a .json config file, does a little processing and spits out an object.

#### /client/sass/sassConfig.js

```js
import config from '../../config.json';

console.log('Generating SASS variables.');
let sass = {
    // some special values here
    };

for (let key of Object.keys(config.style)) {
    sass[key] = config.style[key];
}

sass.debug = (process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production').trim() === 'development';

export default sass;
```

The json file includes comments, so I'm stripping them away with another trivial loader.  This simply parses the json file using [json5](https://github.com/json5/json5), then stringifies the output and passes it on.

#### /webpack-loaders/remove-json-comments-loader.js

```js
import json5 from 'json5';

export default function (source) {
    return JSON.stringify(json5.parse(source));
}
```

My webpack.config.babel.js includes rules for sass and json files to use these two loaders.

#### /webpack.config.babel.js

```js
// ... imports ...

const webpackConfig = {
    entry: {
        app: './client/script.js',
    },

    output: {
        filename: 'script.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    },

    resolveLoader: {
        alias: {
            'js-to-sass-loader': path.resolve(__dirname, 'webpack-loaders/js-to-sass-loader'),
            'remove-json-comments-loader': path.resolve(__dirname, 'webpack-loaders/remove-json-comments-loader')
        }
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'remove-json-comments-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ca]ss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        { loader: 'css-loader' },
                        { loader: 'sass-loader' },
                        { loader: 'js-to-sass-loader' },
                    ]
                }),
            },
            // ...
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        // ...
        new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'style.css' }),
        // ...
    ],

    // ...
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

In a few of my JavaScript files, I can `import Config from './path/to/config.json'` with no problem.  It correctly uses the `remove-json-comments-loader`.  But when my `js-to-sass-loader` attempts to require `sassConfig.js`, Webpack doesn't use the loader for parsing `config.json`.  It attempts to load it as a regular json file, which causes it to fail due to the comments.  I've tried using `import config from '!!remove-json-comments-loader!../../config.json';` but webpack says it cannot find the file.

I'm super new to writing webpack loaders, so I'm sure it's something simple.  Help?  Thanks!

Here's a link to the github repo: https://github.com/dfoverdx/PokeStreamer-Tools/tree/9b4c7315d5dc6b30c5972a0b8678489598311bf0

To reproduce the issue, open up `/node/client/sass/sassConfig.js`, and change the first four lines to:

```
// import json5 from 'json5';
// import fs from 'fs';
// const config = json5.parse(fs.readFileSync('config.json'));
import config from '../../config.json';
```

That is, comment the first 3 lines and uncomment the 4th.

From `/node` run `npm run build` to produce the error.

Comment: Can you create a sample git repo for this? Would be easier to debug

Comment: @TarunLalwani I added a link at the bottom of the OP

Comment: How to get the error? I ran build and start and it all worked fine for me?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified.  Build is the one that matters (start runs the server; build generates the client).  To produce the error, open `/node/client/sass/sassConfig.js`, comment the 3rd line and uncomment the 4th.

Comment: Please join the chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166706/webpack-loader-not-being-used-when-requiring-file-being-processed-by-custom-load

Comment: @dfoverdx, what webpack version are you targeting?

Comment: @hendrathings Webpack v4.1.0

Comment: @dfoverdx, what would expected for this loader? Im not getting error in my env

Comment: Did you download the specified commit in the link?  I've since done a workaround that avoids the error.

Comment: @dfoverdx, yes I did it. It's get variable from `config.style`. I have check it `public/style.css` for sample `body` `background-color` turn into `blue`.

Comment: @hendrathings did you comment the 3rd line and uncomment the 4th of sassConfig.js?

Comment: @dfoverdx, Yes, but it turn error because the script use that dependency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166933/discussion-between-dfoverdx-and-hendrathings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as discussed earlier, below are my observations

- You are trying to create a loader
- Your loader requires files directly using the `require` native nodejs method
- Your `js-to-sass-loader` requires the `sassConfig.js` which then requires the `config.json` file directly
- The `config.json` is the native file which has comments and hence can't be required as such

So the key takeout is that you are mixing webpack which is basically about bundling stuff into bundles and then requiring the bundled code. That is why the json work in rest of the code and not in the `sassConfig.js`.

A loader ideally shouldn't `require` processed `json` file itself. The processed `json` file are suppose to land in the bundle and not as a part of your loader's internal code. So its better to just use the workaround that you are using to load the `config.json` using the `json5` module, this make sure your loader is not looking for modified code itself